# Jasmin-TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'controller.setFocusCompany(obj)')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to test a small method call using Jasmin

JavaScript

```
  vm.gotoBenchmark = function() {
   $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
   $rootScope.$broadcast('benchmarkLoader', true);
   userService.setFocusCompany(vm.company, true);
  };
```

and the test case i am writting is

```
describe('gotoBenchmark', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        var obj = {
            'name':"Apple",'id':2828
        };
        spyOn(testuserService, 'setFocusCompany');
        controller.setFocusCompany(obj);
    });

    it('setFocusCompany', function() {
        expect(testuserService.setFocusCompany).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I would really appreciate your suggestions
Thanks You

Comment: You call `controller.setFocusCompany(obj)` but seems `setFocusCompany` is `userService` method.

Comment: yes it is .http://plnkr.co/edit/ToWKMUsMI9zHvu11pSzu?p=catalogue

Comment: I have added a plnkr to the full test script ,where i have injected the dependencies ,but i am not sure of this Error message                                       ✗ setFocusCompany
 TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'controller.setFocusCompany(obj)')
     at /vagrant/frontend/src/app/companyProfile/companyProfile.controller.spec.js:90

 Expected spy setFocusCompany to have been called.